# python inotify module failing install

Tags: python, python-2.7, inotify

I tried installing and running the python inotify  module but it failed with the below error:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inotify
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "inotify.py", line 3, in <module>
    import inotify.adapters
ImportError: No module named adapters
>>>
```

OS :- Ubuntu 16.04

Module location :- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify

I couldn't find anything specific related to this failure.  Any idea why its failing?

Comment: Try `pip uninstall inotify` and then `pip install inotify==0.2.8` and see if that helps.

Comment: @AetherUnbound i had same version installed still i tried and result is same. it failed

Comment: Hmm, try upgrading pip and try uninstall/reinstall again?

Comment: already tried upgrading pip , it up-to-date

Comment: It might be that the cached version of the wheel pip has stored is corrupt (happened to me before with a different package). Try `pip install inotify==0.2.7` and see if it still happens.

Comment: still no luck with inotify--0.2.7 , this one failed too

Comment: My next thought would be try reinstalling python. You might also try virtual environments with Anaconda

Comment: Any chance you named your script `inotify.py`?

Comment: Be sure you're using the same version of when you use pip, and when you run the script.